# CollapsiblePanelExtender: Can I initiate collapse/expand from client-side javascript? (AJAX Control Toolkit)

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

The CollapsiblePanelExtender seems primarily designed to collapse/expand things in response to user mouse events. Is there also a good way to get the extender to collapse/expand things in response to client-side javascript?

In my particular case, I have a number of CollapsiblePanelExtenders (and their corresponding Panels) on a page, and I'm wondering if I could implement an "expand all panels" button by doing something like this strictly on the client side:

```
for each CollapsiblePanelExtender on this page, call somethingOrOther(extender)
```

I can implement this logic server-side instead if I did a full postback, but my page takes a long time to load, and so this doesn't seem like it would provide a very slick user experience. Thus I am interested in doing expand/collapse client-side.

It seems like this isn't a use case the AJAX Control Toolkit people had in mind, but I thought I'd check.

Comment: If its done originally in javascript, it should definitely be possible. However, I don't feel like rummaging through the source, so perhaps post the functions in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partly working solution now.

I followed Ian's suggestion and looked through the toolkit source. In `CollapsiblePanelBehavior.debug.js`, you can that `expandPanel()` is apparently intended as part of the public interface for the behavior. There's also a `get_Collapsed()`. The key to accessing these behaviors in javascript seems to be setting the `BehaviorID` property on your `CollapsiblePanelExtender` tags in ASP.NET.

I modified the repeater on my page so that the `BehaviorID`s are predictible, along these lines:

```html
<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender 
    BehaviorID="<%#'collapsebehavior'+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,'id')%>"
    ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender" runat="server" />
```

This results with behaviors named `collapsebehavior1`, `collapsebehavior2`, `collapsebehavior3`, etc..

With this done, I'm able to expand all the collapsible panels on the client as follows:

```javascript
function expandAll() {
    var i = 0;
    while (true) {
        i++;
        var name = 'collapsebehavior' + i;
        var theBehavior = $find(name);
        if (theBehavior) {
            var isCollapsed = theBehavior.get_Collapsed();
            if (isCollapsed) {
                theBehavior.expandPanel();
            }             
        } else {
            // No more more panels to examine
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure using `$find` in a loop like that is really inefficient, but that's what I have so far.

Also, it doesn't work on Firefox for some reason. (On FF only the first element expands, and then there's a Javascript error inside the Control Toolkit code.)

This will all seem extremely ugly to all you javascript pros. Maybe I'll clean things up later, or you can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Write the following code in the OnClick event of Image/button

```
<asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" OnClick="ExpandCollapse()"/>  

function ExpandCollapse() {
    $find("collapsibleBehavior1").set_Collapsed(true);
    $find("collapsibleBehavior2").set_Collapsed(true);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just toggle the panels to switch between collapsed/expanded states:

```
    function toggle() {
        var MenuCollapser = $find("name");
        MenuCollapser.togglePanel();
    }
```

Comment: Sure, although in this case I want "expand all", rather than "toggle all", so I'd still need to call theBehavior.get_Collapsed and only toggle conditional on that.