# How do I collapse this form when clicking the ".submit" button?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, collapsable

I have a collapsible (enter your credit card info) form.  When I click it it opens, but when I click submit I want it to close.  Here's my html:

```
<div class= "addStuff">
<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" id="ccdiv">
   <h5> New credit card</h5>         
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <form id = "myForm">
        <input type="password" name="credit_card_number" id="credit_card_number" value="" placeholder="Credit Card Number">
        <input type="password" name="security_code" id="security_code" value="" placeholder="Security Code">
        <input type="date" name="expiration_date" id="expiration_date" value="" placeholder="Expiration Date">
        <input type="password" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name On Card">
        <input type="password" name="street_address" id="street_address" value="" placeholder="Street Address">
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" placeholder="City">
        <input type="number" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" value="" placeholder="Zip Code">

            <button type="button" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.submit').click(function(){
    var creditcard = $('#credit_card_number').val();
    $('.accounts #CreditCards div[data-role="content"] #swipeMe').append('<li data-swipeurl="#" ><a href="#">' + creditcard + '</a></li>');
   // refresh view 
   $('#CreditCards ul').listview('refresh');

   // hide form
 alert('test'); 


 $('#myForm').slideUp();
 $('#myForm').trigger('collapse');

    });
});
```

Comment: attach the trigger event to submit, along with click

Comment: Why your inputs are not inside your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a JsFiddle I worked on to try and get your code working
http://jsfiddle.net/rvqRX/

I went thru line by line and commented each one out one at a time and found that the only line I had to comment out for it to behave correctly was this

```
$('#CreditCards ul').listview('refresh');
```

Not sure why... does it make any sense to you?

Comment: It makes no sense to me, but it totally works.  Must be a jQuery Mobile thing or whatever but u are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ID` to your form `<form id="myForm">...</form>`

Collapse your form where you want using a [JQuery animation](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) :

```
$('#myForm').slideUp();
```

Comment: I put everything in a form and tried that, but still nothing.  You can see my edits in the example above.  WHat am I doing wrong? THanks :)

Comment: Just add the id to the form

Comment: Even $('#myForm').hide(); ?

Comment: Still nothing.  Could it be a jQueryMobile thing?

Comment: Yes it could! By design, the JS code of your loaded page is not executed. Only the JS code of the first file loaded is taking into account. Try to put an ´alert('test')´ call in your click event. If the alert message is not displayed, your code is not executed. If it is the case, I will update my answer with a workaround

Comment: Yeah the alert didn't pop up.  I edited into the example, so u could see if I added it correctly.  Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

On submit() of form, make sure your trigger to collapse the form is called using JQuery method . Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but what does that look like `$('#myForm').trigger('collapse');` doesn't seem to work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065730/collapsiblepanelextender-can-i-initiate-collapse-expand-from-client-side-javasc 

Hope this helps.